# Insert millon data with TypeOrm and Oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, nestjs, typeorm

I am currently having a problem, I need to insert a large amount of data, greater than 100K into an Oracle database from node using TypeOrm.
The problem is that when using the ".save ()" method, if the amount of data exceeds 4000 rows, the data is duplicated in Oracle and I do not understand the reason, besides that it takes too long to insert, approximately 30min in 150K records.

What is the most efficient way to insert a large amount of data in a small amount of time?

Comment: To solve the duplication problem, we would need to know more about  your database schema and the process you're using.  Seeing some code would be nice.

Comment: 4000 what ? rows, bytes?  ORM will not be as performant as native sql. Where is all this data coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Bulk inserts can be performed according to the documentation [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/insert-query-builder):

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(User)
    .values([
        { firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" }, 
        { firstName: "Phantom", lastName: "Lancer" }
     ])
    .execute();
```

> This is the most efficient way in terms of performance to insert rows into your database. You can also perform bulk insertions this way.

I'm not sure about the duplicate issue you are facing.

Comment: Your link points to this question

Comment: @AJ Fixed. Must have been a copy paste error.